# Azure Devops pipeline with xUnit and SonarCloud

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, xunit

Does anyone know if running parallel assemblies to true for xUnit will work with SonarCloud when collecting test coverage? Our unit tests are running long, so we found in the xUnit documentation that you can run this command to have the assemblies run in parallel..."-- xunit.parallelizeAssembly=true". The issue with this though is that now our test coverage doesn't publish the correct test coverage results from that PR.

It's like the placement of the collect XPlat code coverage or the xunit parallel assembly will only run one of them, whichever comes first. If I have the parallel assembly before the XPlat argument, then our unit test step will run twice as fast, but then it won't collect the code coverage. If the collect code coverage is first, then the unit test step is back to taking just as long again.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: dotnet test
  inputs:
    command: test
    arguments: '--no-build --configuration ${{ buildConfiguration }} --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage;Format=opencover" -- xunit.parallelizeAssembly=true'
```

Answer (score 0):

If parallel assembly is before the XPlat argument, it appears the command will **ignore** the `--collect` setting specified, but use default DataCollector setting.

My Datacollector setting:
[image]

`coverage.cobertura.xml` is created in Pipeline result, which is not `opencover` format:
[image]

If `parallel assembly` is after the XPlat argument, `opencover` result is created:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response! This is kind of interesting. I was convinced that dotnet test does accept that as an argument; perhaps it was just so much faster because it wasn't running the test assemblies sequentially and collecting the test coverage and had me thinking that it was actually testing the assemblies in parallel. So maybe the actual hold up is the collecting of test coverage. We have probably over 100+ project test assemblies in our solution, so it's a big undertaking to add the xunit.runner.json to all projects. Will have to look into this some more.

Comment: Thanks @Aoguye for the reply. After further investigation, i find the command in the [xunit runsettings doc](https://xunit.net/docs/runsettings#switches), it supports to append the argument to the `dotnet test` command. I have updated the reply above.